# Devanagari ( Indian ) fonts are not being rendered by browsers

Tags: java, browser, fonts, devanagari

I've developed java swing application for newspaper shop. When I make bill order by running my project from Netbeans, the bill is saved as an HTML file on given directory and devanagari fonts are rendered properly.
eg.
[image]

But when I deploy my swing application as an EXE Installer file and tried same thing then I found that Devanagari characters are replaced by question mark.

eg.
[image]

In short, Everything is rendered properly by browsers when I try to make bill by running project in Netbeans. After deploying same project as an EXE application, bill font is not rendered properly by browsers.

The code to write Data from JTable to Html File is as follow.

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    static DBConnect db;
    Object[][] rowdata;
    static String[] columnheads;
    static DefaultTableModel dtm;
    static ResultSet rs;
    static ResultSetMetaData rsmt;
    String curName,shop,address,owner,contact,sign,data,destPath;
    static int rows,columns,number;
    float total, discount;
    static TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter;
    Vector curRow;
    ActionListener menuListener;
    Writer out;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    File file;
    JFileChooser chooser;
```

---

```
void printBill()
    {
        // bPrev.setValues(tBno.getText(), tDate.getText(), tCustomer.getText(), tTotal.getText(), tTotal2.getText(), tPrevBal.getText());

       try
       {
           rs=db.stmt.executeQuery("select value from SETTINGS where property='shop'");
           rs.next();
           shop=rs.getString(1);

           rs=db.stmt.executeQuery("select value from SETTINGS where property='address'");
           rs.next();
           address=rs.getString(1);

           rs=db.stmt.executeQuery("select value from SETTINGS where property='owner'");
           rs.next();
           owner=rs.getString(1);

           rs=db.stmt.executeQuery("select value from SETTINGS where property='contact'");
           rs.next();
           contact=rs.getString(1);

           rs=db.stmt.executeQuery("select value from SETTINGS where property='sign'");
           rs.next();
           sign=rs.getString(1);

           rs=db.stmt.executeQuery("select value from SETTINGS where property='savePath'");
           rs.next();
           destPath=rs.getString(1);

           dtm = (DefaultTableModel) BillTbl.getModel();
           file=new File(destPath+"Bill-"+tBno.getText()+".html");

           out=new FileWriter(file);
           bw=new BufferedWriter(out);

           bw.write("<header><title> Bill-No "+tBno.getText()+"</title></head><body><p align=center> <b> "+shop+" </b><br> <b> पत्ता : </b> "+address+" <br> <b> मालक : </b> "+owner+" <br> <b> भ्रमणध्वनी क्र. </b> "+contact+" <br>--------------------------------------------</br> <b> बिलक्रमांक : </b> "+tBno.getText()+"  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <b> दिनांक : </b> "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").format(new java.util.Date())+" <br> <b> ग्राहकाचे नाव : </b> "+tCustomer.getText()+" &nbsp &nbsp</p>");

           bw.write("<center><table border=1><tr>");
           for (int i=0;i<dtm.getColumnCount();i++)
           {
               if(i==0 || i==2 || i==4)
               {
                   bw.write("<th> &nbsp "+dtm.getColumnName(i)+" &nbsp </th>");
               }     
           }
           bw.write("</tr>");

           for (int i=0;i<dtm.getRowCount();i++)
           {
             bw.write("<tr>");
             for (int j=0;j<dtm.getColumnCount();j++)
             {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    bw.write("<td> &nbsp "+dtm.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+" &nbsp </td>");
                }
                else if(j==2 || j==4)
                {
                    bw.write("<td align=center>"+dtm.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"</td>");
                }
             }
             bw.write("</tr>");
          }
          bw.write("</table><br><table border=0><tr><td rowspan=3><img src='"+sign+"' height=40 width=70></td><td align=right> रक्कम रू. "+tTotal.getText()+"/- </td></tr><tr><td align=right> देयक रक्कम रू. "+tPrevBal.getText()+"/- </td></tr><tr><td align=right> <b> एकूण रक्कम रू. "+tTotal2.getText()+"/- </b> </td></tr></table></center></body>");
          bw.close();

          Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Check database setting for UTF-8 for other languages.

Comment: Yes, I've already set Database Character set to AL32UTF

Comment: You have to make changes for character set in html/jsp page also. You can find more details in google

Comment: Everything works fine when I make bill by running software on netbeans. But after deploying same application, if I try to make order ( bill ) then browsers shows ???? instead of characters.

Comment: I've tried  <meta charset="UTF-8">  in HTML file, but it does not work too

Comment: How exactly are you deploying app as an EXE?

Comment: Post the smallest stripped down version of the HTML file that demonstrates the font problem. Delete most of the content before posting here.

Comment: "Clean and Build" options makes jar file of project in 'projectDirectory/dist'.
Then I use Excelsior Jet named software to convert this jar file to EXE installer.

Comment: When I run application in Netbeans, content is written to html file dynamically with devanagari font as expected.

But when I run same application without netbeans, it writes question marks ( ??? ) instead of Devanagari letters in html file.

Comment: I half suspect that this _also_ doesn't work in the HTML version on computers that don't have devanagari fonts installed. It feels very much like you're relying on fonts being available without every putting in the code that _ensures_ the font is used. So, create a new dir, and then create a [mcve]: do you tell Java which font asset to use, and do you make sure it gets (LEGALLY!) bundled with your executable?

Comment: “…when I deploy my swing application as an EXE Installer file…” On the same computer, or on a different computer?

Comment: On same computer and on different computers too.

Comment: I've used DVOT-YogeshMR font.